# Update trigger to ensure matching values in other table Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, constraints, conditional-statements

I am trying to come up with a way to make sure that when a table is updated, that a certain condition is met. Can this be done in a trigger? I have made the following two tables, storeTable and employeeTable.

I need to make sure that when storeManager is updated in the storeTable, that the employee has a storeID that matches the store in which I am trying to update the storeManager. (employee cannot be manager of a store he does not work at)

In addition, I need to make sure that the employee exists in the employeeTable. I was thinking some sort of CASE statement would be best, but dont know how this could be enforced by a trigger.

I was thinking about morphing the "Foreign Key Trigger for Child Table" trigger example from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm#1007172 but I could not figure out how to change this to fit my specific need. Any help is much appreciated.

For context, the current keys are:

storeTable:

storeID PRIMARY KEY

employeeTable:

empID PRIMARY KEY

storeID FOREIGN KEY REFERS TO storeTable.storeID

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it seems that constraints can do the job. You don't need triggers.

Here's how. First, create tables without any constraints. Then add them, both primary and foreign key ones which will be `deferrable` (otherwise you wouldn't be able to insert any rows as parent keys don't exist yet).

```
SQL> create table employee
  2    (empid        number,
  3     fname        varchar2(10),
  4     storeid      number
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create table store
  2    (storeid      number,
  3     storename    varchar2(20),
  4     storemanager number
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table employee add constraint pk_employee  primary key (empid, storeid);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table store    add constraint pk_store     primary key (storeid);

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table store    add constraint fk_store_emp foreign key (storemanager, storeid)
  2    references employee (empid, storeid)
  3    deferrable initially deferred;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table employee add constraint fk_emp_store foreign key (storeid)
  2    references store (storeid)
  3    deferrable initially deferred;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Now let's add some data: initial insert into `employee` will be OK until I commit - then it'll fail because its store doesn't exist yet:

```
SQL> insert into employee values (1, 'John' , 1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;
commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.FK_EMP_STORE) violated - parent key not
found


SQL>
```

But, if I don't commit and pay attention to what I'm entering (i.e. that referential integrity is maintained), it'll be OK:

```
SQL> insert into employee values (1, 'John' , 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into employee values (2, 'Matt' , 2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into store values (1, 'Santa Clara', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into store values (2, 'San Francisco', 2);   --> note 2 as STOREID

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * From employee;

     EMPID FNAME         STOREID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 John                1
         2 Matt                2

SQL> select * From store;

   STOREID STORENAME            STOREMANAGER
---------- -------------------- ------------
         1 Santa Clara                     1
         2 San Francisco                   2

SQL>
```

See? So far so good.

Now I'll try to modify `STORE` table and set its manager to `John` who works in `storeid = 1` which means that it should fail:

```
SQL> update store set storemanager = 1
  2  where storeid = 2;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;
commit
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.FK_STORE_EMP) violated - parent key not
found


SQL>
```

As expected.

Let's now add emplyoee `ID = 6`, `Jimmy`, who works in `storeid = 2` and set him to be manager in San Francisco (`storeid = 2`):

```
SQL> insert into employee values (6, 'Jimmy', 2);

1 row created.

SQL> update store set storemanager = 6
  2  where storeid = 2;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

Yey! It works!

---

As you can see, no triggers needed.

Note that - if you want to drop any of those tables - you'll fail as they are referenced by each other:

```
SQL> drop table store;
drop table store
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys


SQL> drop table employee;
drop table employee
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys


SQL>
```

It means that you'd first have to drop foreign key constraints, then drop tables:

```
SQL> alter table employee drop constraint fk_emp_store;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table store    drop constraint fk_store_emp;

Table altered.

SQL> drop table store;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table employee;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

---

That's all, I guess.

Comment: This seems way simpler than what I thought I was needing to do! Let me give it a shot shortly and I'll report back!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, storeid is a primary key and a foreign key in both tables? Can a row be a PK and FK at the same time?

Comment: Obviously, it can. Why not?

Comment: Just didn't know that, I'm very new to this haha.

Comment: We all were, don't worry :)

Comment: I seem to be getting this...

ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key
02260. 00000 -  "table can have only one primary key"
*Cause:    Self-evident.
*Action:   Remove the extra primary key.

Comment: As it says: self-evident. You are doing something wrong; don't add two primary keys. Look what & how I did that.